# importError pdfkit with docker ask for wkhtmltopdf

Tags: python, pip

I have an importError on my container when I want it to run pdfkit. It actually ask for wkhtmltopdf.

I looked for it and install it on my image, but I still have the exact same error.

here is the output I get :

```
raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, stderr))
OSError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code -6. error:
The switch --no-outline, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :1
```

How do I fix this ? Is there something more to install ?

Comment: pdfkit works around wkhtmltopdf executable , so you may need to keep the executable in docker environment, since all are virtualized it wont have access to local paths unless you provide it explicity also it need Xvfb header which on some machine we need to install manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go in you container, what is the output of this command?

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

If you don't have any, export it :

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

Then,check in your container if there is any /tmp/.X1-lock file. If yes, remove it and relaunch `Xvfb :1 &`.

Retry whatever script that failed and see if you still have the same error ;)